# Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, access-control

i got this problem any one there to help me solve this problem, this is really aching.
I am using swipejs for the carousal on ipad, so it works fine till i am not including jquery.js
but when i include the jquery.js script it gives the following error
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://localhost/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Digital/phonegap/www/swipe.js?_=1352274440669. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

can any body help me. Thankyou

Comment: It should be `http://` not `file://`

Comment: That filepath sure does look funny. I'd consider checking the source for the place that swipe.js is fetched. There shouldn't be "file://" at the beginning - it should just be from localhost/.... If you don't know or cant find it manually, I'd open it in Chrome and check the Initiator column of the Network tab in the dev-tools (Ctrl-Shit-I) It may be something else, but that path is wrong and (I think) should be resolved first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 sides for enabling cors
1. Client Side
        Make sure that Cors is enabled.It can be done by meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*" or use any others option.

1. Server Side
      Make sure that Cors is enabled in server side.
   Consider above url  fire in rest client or advanced rest client and check cors is enabled if it is enabled then response message should have this Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * in header

Solution to  your Problem is that above url  may not be cors enabled  and pls check by firing url with  using advanced restclient in chrome
  in  client side is enabled as default or not please enabled it .